# How to write software for Windows using Java?

Tags: java, user-interface

I have just learned Java in my college. However, in that I can just write programs that are run in the command line. How can I create GUI softwares using Java, something like Notepad? I'm really sorry for asking such a basic question on this forum, but I am really interested in writing real-world software. Also, I've heard a lot about Python. How can I develop similar software using Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) to develop Java GUI/desktop applications for Windows.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

[NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) is also an option.

For Python, check these links:

[GUI Programming in Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming)

[Is Python any good for GUI development?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/115495/114029)

Comment: I think recommending tools is a bit premature at this point... Eclipse is not so much for GUI development but for Java development in general.

Answer (score 13):

Java: [Trail: Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Python: [GUI Programming in Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming)

And since you mentioned creating a simple text editor, [here's](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/examples/components/editor/nutpad.html) an example.

Comment: And http://www.jedit.org/ (JEdit) is a significantly more advanced Editor in Java :)

Answer (score 2):

Start by using an integrated development environment such as [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) or [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org). Both of them are free.

Both have visual editors to graphically design your program and assist you writing the actions performed in the code when you e.g. click a button or so. Personally I prefer Netbeans for this purpose as the gui designer does not need to be added as an optional plugin (maybe this is also not necessary any more for Eclipse).

Of course, to go beyond the first steps, you will need to read some documentation on how to build GUIs as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to write native windows apps you might also consider switching to .Net (c#) which is not too hard to learn when you know programming basics in java.

.net is much better integrated in the windows environment and I think visual studio has a notepad example lying around somewhere.

Not saying you can't do this in java, sure you can.

Answer (score 1):

Use netbeans, it has a old but good visual development mode. I cannot remember perfectly but it uses swing library i guess. Also it lets you develop not for only windows, but for mobile phones etc if you install the right plugin.

Answer (score 0):

i think for beginners netbean is good because its interface is user friendly. 
it manages the code in well define manner and make code easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

You can use IntelliJ:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

This is a very good Java IDE if you want to become,
going to become, or are already a developer.